# How to dump joomla users and user profile to excel correctly

Tags: sql, excel, joomla

I need to download Joomla users and user profile data to an excel table. I am using a Joomla components "VJ SQL to File" which require that a SQL query is entered. Now the problem starts.
I have entered following query:

```
select
vpa1_user_profiles.user_id, 
vpa1_user_profiles.profile_key,         
vpa1_user_profiles.profile_value,
vpa1_users.name,
vpa1_users.username,
vpa1_users.email
from
vpa1_users
inner join vpa1_user_profiles
on
vpa1_users.id = vpa1_user_profiles.user_id
```

And the result is like shown below:

```
user_id profile_key  profile_value          name username     email
4256    profile.dob  "1999-12-31 23:00:00"  Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.modnr "09080706"            Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.nr     "22"                 Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.ort "Pfefferland"           Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.plz "9876"                  Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.str "Landstr."          Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.telnr "01020304"            Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.username  "Test"            Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
4256    profile.uservor   "User"            Test Testuser1234 abcdefg.hi
```

The 3 right end columns are from the vpa1_users table and the 3 left end columns are from the vpa1_user_profiles table.
But what I need is an Excel table with one record each row.

Any advise on how to solve this problem or if anybody has a better idea on how to get the dump in one excel file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on a MySQL database you could use group_concat:

```
SELECT user_profiles.user_id, users.name, users.username, users.email, user_profiles.profile_values
FROM x2iu9_users AS users
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT( profile_value
SEPARATOR  ',' ) profile_values
FROM x2iu9_user_profiles
GROUP BY user_id
) AS user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
```

I think that's the best way to solve your problem.

It is clear that a JOIN/INNER JOIN/LEFT JOIN will produce multiple rows per ID because Joomla stores every user_profile key/value pair as a separate row.

(I tested this on my own Joomla DB and it will produce this output:

```
user_id name username email            profile_values
89      name1 uname1  example@mail.com "23521","","","","","","","","","",false
```

)

Comment: thanks for the hint. The problem is that the Excel file should have only one value each cell. The profile _value contains a string in your proposed solution.